# Cannot access JSON Object because of "wrapper"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The idea is that I call a REST API, get returned a JSON array, and then build that array into a table.

When the API call returns the array, it wraps everything inside a "result" object, which is making it difficult for me to actually access anything within the array. Is there a way to strip away that "result" layer so that I am actually able to do what I need to do.

At the moment, calling something like `obj.result` returns undefined, where obj is the `JSON.parse`ed version of the response that I got from the API.

I have included a snippet of what a returned response is, and the code that I'm using to try and process this.

```
{
    "result": [{
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "question about 1010 EB1",
        "number": "INC1785295"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "Software Update",
        "number": "INC1785559"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "RI 113 - Not Displaying Laptop VGA",
        "number": "INC1785587"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "[HD] SAS 2229: Lectern PC",
        "number": "INC1785640"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "SAS 2229",
        "number": "INC1785644"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "Aerial Email Manager: BU 2111: Lectern PC Down",
        "number": "INC1785671"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "Burlington Labs 2111",
        "number": "INC1785673"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "EB3 2207: Training Request",
        "number": "INC1785703"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "BU 2111: Lectern PC",
        "number": "INC1785759"
    }, {
        "incident_state": "7",
        "short_description": "[RC] SAS 1220: Telephone",
        "number": "INC1785812"
    }, ]
}
```

```js
var response = null;

function getAction(){
    document.getElementById("expanded").innerHTML = "Calling...";
    var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("GET","https://demo.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/incident?sysparm_fields=short_description,number,incident_state");
    client.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
    client.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState = this.DONE){
            document.getElementById("expanded").innerHTML = "";
            response = this.response;
            alert("API Call Completed, awaiting processing.");
            //document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this.response;
        }};
    client.send();
}

function processData(){
    var obj = JSON.parse(response);
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.result.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("expanded").innerHTML = obj.result[0][i];
    }
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to include that on my HTML page, there is a button to call getAction(), and then once that wraps up, there is a button to call processData().

Comment: Where did you call that `processData`?  Can't see it in the code.

Comment: My apologies, my html page has a button to call getAction(), and then once that wraps up, there is another button to call processData()

Comment: How do you know once it's wrapped up?

Comment: @BlakeStoddard Maybe you can `console.log(response);` before you pass it and post the log result?

Comment: @EvanKnowles It's left up to the user to wait for the alert box to display before clicking the button to activate processData(). There is no actual code logic behind that.

Comment: Actually it looks like the problem is this: `obj.result[0][i]` which should be `obj.result[i].incident_state` (or whatever property you want to access)

Comment: @Juhana: I'm pretty sure that your diagnosis is correct. Why don't you write an answer so that we can give you some upvotes?

Comment: Probably the root of the problem is in this IF statement: `if(this.readyState = this.DONE){` .... another `=`  char is missing

Comment: @Juhana As LukeH said, go ahead and write that as an answer so that you can get the upvotes -- that took care of the problem I was having. No clue why I hadn't done that from the beginning. Must just be too early in the morning.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5ft2grq9/ removed the comma at the end of your json and tried it. working !!

Comment: leo.fcx got a point too tho.

Comment: @JavaScript: Yes indeed. I guess in this case `this.DONE` is truthy in some way, so the `if` clause always evaluates as true (even if the call fails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are looping throught the elements of your json array, but you are trying to access wrong properties or wrong values.

Because, as mentioned in comments, with `obj.result[0][i]` you are always trying to get the element with index `i` from the first object in the array.

Try to change it like this :

```
obj.result[i].someProperty
```

Or maybe:

```
obj.result[i]["someKey"]
```

**EDIT:**

Also note that your if condition is not corerct, because you are not comparing here:

```
if(this.readyState = this.DONE)
```

You should use `==` for comparison because `=` is used for assignement.

Comment: I think the problem was that `obj.result` is `undefined` ... so this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

As `@open and free` mentioned, this is a JSON.parse issue ... removing the last comma char inside the array, it works

Comment: I actually forgot to remove that comma when I edited down that JSON excerpt. The actual response is much much longer, I just didn't want to include the entire thing.